# POST request working only once in Nodejs Expressjs MVC application

Tags: node.js, express

I'm very newbie to nodejs.I'm practicing an Nodejs with express in MVC architecture with MySQL. All things are working fine, but I wonder why this application working POST request only once after server start.

**This is my Controller**

```
const IncData = require("../../models/Accounts_Models/Income_Model");

module.exports = {
    create_income_head(req,res){

        IncData.m_add_inc_head(req.con , req.body, function (err)
            {
                res.send(err);
            }

        )
    }
};
```

**My Model**

```
module.exports={
    m_add_inc_head: function (con,data,callback){
        con.query('CALL Create_Income_Head (?,?,?,?,?,?)',[data.income_category,data.description,1,0,'',''],callback);
    },
};
```

**My Router**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const income = require("../../controllers/Accounts_Controllers/Income_Controller");

router.post("/add_income_head",income.create_income_head);
module.exports = router;
```

Someone please explain what went wrong in this code?

Comment: What happened  after "once"?

Comment: Throwing **Cannot POST /** error , Status code: **404 Not Found**

Comment: Make sure that your client POST to `/add_income_head` instead of `/`

Answer (score 0):

In your request **you don't have successful response** (so after request client side waits response but it's only for errors), try:

```
module.exports = {
    create_income_head(req,res) {
        IncData.m_add_inc_head(req.con , req.body, function (err) {
            if(err) {
              res.send(err);
            }

            // or just res.send('some message');
            // or res.status(201).end();
            res.status(201).json({ success: true });
        });
    }
};
```